# ¿Cómo capturo el valor de un TMemo en Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pascal, firebird

Tengo una pantalla con 2 botones y quiero capturar el valor que un usuario ingrese en el formulario tal como lo pudiera hacer si tuviese un Edit.Text, ¿cómo lo hago?

Por ejemplo aquí si funciona:

```
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin                         
       if (Edit1.Text <> '') then   
            begin  
            VCASO:=Edit1.Text;  
            Self.Close;
            end               
        else 
            showmessage ('No puede dejar el campo vacío.');
end;
```

Pero eso solo toma una línea, yo quiero un TMemo porque me captura varias líneas, agradezco su ayuda.

---

**Actualización:**

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
{$FORM TCasos, Ficha de Casos.sfm}

uses
  Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin                         
       if (Memo1.Text <> '') then   
            begin  
            VCASO:=Memo1.Text;  
            Self.Close;
            end               
        else 
            showmessage ('No puede dejar el campo vacío.');
end; 

procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
      Self.Close;
end;        

begin
end;
```

Cuando trato de ejecutarlo me dice:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues lo mismo aplica para un TMemo, con su propiedad 'Text' puedes acceder al texto que contenga, ejemplo: variableString := Memo1.Text;

Comment: Hola Antonio, muchas gracias por ayudarme, pero cuando coloco en lugar del Edit1.Text un Memo1.Text me arroja un error "Unknown member identifier: 'Text' :( @antonio291093

Comment: Fijate si cuando añades el TMemo al form se te añade en la declaracion de componentes en la seccion 'type' al inicio del formulario

Comment: @antonio291093 actualice la pregunta a ver si así me doy a explicar un poco mejor, te he copiado todo, de antemano muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes leer el contenido del *Memo* valiéndote de su propiedad `Lines`, que es un [`TStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TStrings). Es decir, puedes acceder a ella linea por línea ([`Strings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Strings) es la propiedad *default*) o al texto completo –incluyendo caracteres de fin de línea– mediante su propiedad [`Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Text).

Por ejemplo:

```
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Texto: string;
begin
  for I := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
    ShowMessage('Línea ' + IntToStr(I) + #13 + Memo1.Lines[I]);
  //o bien el texto completo
  Texto := Memo1.Lines.Text;
  ShowMessage(Texto);
end;
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono el Memo1.Lines.Text!!

Answer (score 0):

```html
unit Unit10;

interface

uses
  Forms, Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls;

type
  TForm10 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form10: TForm10;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var textoMemo : String;
begin
  if (Memo1.Text <> '') then
    begin
      textoMemo:=Memo1.Text;
      showmessage(textoMemo);
    end
  else
  begin
    showmessage ('No puede dejar el campo vacío.');
  end;
end;
end.
```

Con la propiedad Text del componente TMemo puedes acceder al contenido de este, verifica los uses y que este declarado correctamente dentro del bloque type.

P.D: Realice el ejemplo en delphi 10.2.3

Comment: gracias, no me funciono de esta manera pero igualmente fue muy útil tu respuesta